# Do indexes help in queries that don't have the indexed column in where clause?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to remove an index in a table whose access in php never uses the indexed column. Index takes up extra space and I am trying to trim it. It's a table of phone numbers. A phone number is linked to a user profile's id. So it has 3 columns. `id` (index), `number` and `person`. I was wondering if removing the index will affect the queries that use `number` or `person` in the where clause. My gut feeling is that it shouldn't but I am afraid computer science doesn't work on gut feelings. The data is accessed via `join`s. For example...

```
SELECT *
FROM people ... LEFT JOIN
     phoneNumbers
     ON people.id = phoneNumbers.person
```

Edit: Apparently no one seems to be able to answer the question in the title.

Comment: If you have selected column or column is in where section or used in joins, indexing does matter (either positive or negative effect). Should column be indexed, that is a whole different question.

Comment: I dont want to index any of the other two columns. I just want to remove the index that I do have on the unused `id` column (and delete the column altogether) without affecting the performance.

Comment: Having a column named "id" and having an index are two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case you show, only the `person` column would benefit from an index.

Indexes help in basically four cases:

- **Row restriction**, that is finding the rows by value instead of examining every row in the table.

  - **Joining** is a subset of row restriction, i.e. each distinct value in the first table looks up matching rows in the second table. Indexing a column that is referenced in the `ON` clause is done in the same way you would index a column referenced in the `WHERE` clause.
- **Sorting**, to retrieve rows in index order instead of having to sort the result set as an additional step.
- **Distinct and Group By**, to scan each distinct value in an index.
- **Covering index**, that is when the query needs only the columns that are found in the index.

In the case of InnoDB, every table is treated as an *index-organized table* based on its primary key, and we should take advantage of this because primary key lookups are very efficient. So if you can redefine a primary key on your `phoneNumbers.person` column (in part), that would be best.

Comment: cool I can make the `person` column an index. But do I remove the `id` column? and what kind of index will the person column be? Since it can have duplicates (one person having more than one phone number) it cannot be PK or unique.

Comment: That's why I said "(in part)," because the `person` column should not be unique. You could use a compound primary key (that is, over two columns). Should you create a primary key? Keep in mind that InnoDB will create one for you if you don't - a six-byte integer column that's invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good idea for all tables to have explicit primary keys and an index necessarily comes with these.  For instance, it becomes difficult to delete rows in the table, if unwanted duplicates were to appear.

In general, indexes are used for `where` clauses, `on` clauses, and `order by`.  If you have an `id` column, then foreign key references to the table should be using that column, and not the other two columns.  The index might also be used for a `select count(*) from table` query, but I'm not 100% sure if MySQL does this.

If removing an index on a column makes that big a difference, then you should be investigating other ways to make your database more efficient.  One method would be using partitioning to store different parts of the database in different files.

Comment: The deleting is not a problem. For unrelated reasons, I have to delete the rows based on the person's id and not the row's id. So I use `DELETE FROM phoneNumbers WHERE person = ?`, same goes for selecting data, always via joins and always with person's id. The row id is literally never used in the entire program ever. I was wondering if having an index less table has any other repercussions.

Comment: If you declare `person` to be a foreign key, you can tell MySQL to cascade deletions from the `people` table, i.e., when you delete a row from the `people` table, all rows in `phonenumbers` with a corresponding `person` column are also deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If the `id` column is an auto-incrementing integer, you have already indexed the table in the most efficient way possible. Removing it will make MySQL treat (`number`, `person`) as the table's primary key, which will cause less efficient look-ups.

Additionally, any index you create in the future will contain two columns, the first being the indexed field in the desired order, the second being the table's primary key. If you remove the `id` column and later decide to index the table on `person`, then your index will be larger than the table itself: each row would be: `| person | (number, person) |`.

Given that you're querying on this relationship, the `person` column **should** be indexed, and leaving the `id` column in place will ensure that the `person` index is as small and as quick as possible.

Comment: so your suggestion is to remove the index but not the `id` column itself and make the `person` column an index. Is that right? Also the person column can have duplicates so it cannot be a unique or primary key. What kind of index would the `person` column be?

Comment: If the `id` column is your primary key, it will always be indexed. As mentioned in Bill Karwin's answer, InnoDB tables are stored already indexed on their primary key. You can create non-unique secondary indexes on whatever column you want; InnoDB will store this as another table with an `| (indexed field) | (primary key) |`.

Comment: Well I am trying to reduce the size. So can i remove the id column (and hence it's index) and make person column as an index? Or maybe have no index at all?

Answer (score 0):

The column "id" seems useless. If I've understood you correctly, I'd

- drop the "id" column,
- add a primary key constraint on {person, number}, and
- a foreign key reference from "person" to people.id.

I'm assuming each person can have more than one phone number.

Creating a primary key constraint has a side-effect that you might not want. It creates an internal index on the key columns.

Comment: wait, I can make more than one columns primary key? TIL. Ok so that looks fine. And I don't think mysql has the concept of a foreign key. At Least it isn't there in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Never mind about phpmyadmin. It is hidden under "relation view"